# mvn appengine:devserver error

Tags: java, maven

I'm using window OS

I'm doing like this (using google api in java)

https://github.com/aliciatang/CalendarSync

when I writing mvn appengine:devserver, It got error

```
[INFO] Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.21/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.21.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34:22 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-04T18:52:58+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.21:devserver (default-cli) on project gcal: Could not resolve SDK artifact in Maven.: Could not transfer artifact com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:zip:1.9.21 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request of: com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/1.9.21/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.21.zip from central failed: Connection reset -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I can't solve this problem!!

Comment: it seems more like a network issue since the last message is:
 Failed: Connection reset.
Try to run maven with the -X switch and post the full log here.

Comment: I use maven 1.3.5

Comment: oh!1 in my company notewook isn't working but my private computer doing well

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. `gcloud components update` //Update gcloud
2. `mvn clean package` //Rebuild app
3. `mvn appengine:run` //Run on local server (Jetty) (This replace: mvn appengine:devserver)
4. Go to the browser: http://localhost:8080/

Happy coding !!!